# Python - What is the best way to round a float up in magnitude to an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, rounding

I have a floating point number which I would like to round to an integer, but always round up (where 'up' means larger in magnitude)

For example, 4.2 would be rounded to 5, and -4.2 would be rounded to -5.0

Is there a nice way to do this that is built into Python? If not, what would you recommend as the most efficient way of performing this operation?

Originally I was just using `math.ceil()`, until I realized `math.ceil(4.2)` gives 5, while `math.ceil(-4.2)` gives -4, which is not what I want.

One way that to get around this is to use `ceil` for positive numbers, and `floor` for the negative ones, but the code starts to look really gross with inline if statements everywhere (I use this operation in multiple places)

Another possibility might be something like `math.copysign( math.ceil( abs( x ) ), x )` which also seems a little excessive

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `copysign(ceil(abs(n)), n)` solution - just stick it in a function (wrapped in `int()`, presumably) and forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to scatter "inline if statements everywhere", you could defined your own function:

```
def my_rounding(x):
    return math.ceil(x) if x > 0. else math.floor(x)
```

:D

Comment: looks like defining my own function is the way to go. I was hoping there would be something built in that might run slightly faster, but the difference is probably negligible :)

Comment: `if .. else` statement ain't that expensive!

Comment: Interesting to note, the `x > 0` part of the expression is evaluated before the `floor` or the `ceil` so only one of the two options needs to be evaluated, which is really nice. I was worried it might evaluate both.
I just discovered this from [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html)

Comment: @Brent This is the syntax for the Python "ternary conditional operator". Some like it. Some dislike it ;) As of performances, you shouldn't worry to much about that. As @Golgauth said, `if...else` is efficient. Function call are a little bit less. But it shouldn’t be a concern. Really. Once your program will work, if profiling shows this function as a major bottleneck -- that day, you could start to think about "optimization". Not before :D

Answer (score 5):

> but the code starts to look really gross with inline if statements everywhere (I use this operation in multiple places)

Then write a function:

```
def myround(flt):
   return math.ceil(flt) if flt > 0.0 else math.floor(flt)
```